# Accidental Plagiarism

Tags: university, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

So I have had a bad few weeks and I had an essay due on Monday. I decided to use an old essay to help me. I took a couple of sentences from my old work that were direct quotes and some that were not (which turned out to be quotes unreferenced). I have a 25% turnitin score and I have last accessed 09/11/2013 on my reference list twice... I wanted to submit so I didn't look like I could not cope with the course however, I have letters that verify I could have had extenuating circumstances. I want to talk to my tutor but I am so scared to. What do I do please? I am so worried.

Comment: In which sense is this "accidental"?

Comment: Talk to your tutor. If you have letters explaining your situation this is a hundred times better than cheating.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you're asking here. Did you just realise that you plagiarised in your old work, or did you just quote verbatim from your old work and that is the plagiarism you're concerned about? (Because I can see how reading your old work and reusing thoughts you had there would not be plagiarism, but would look very bad if you accidentally repeated the same expressions verbatim.)

Answer (score 2):

There are realistically two things you can do here. You can bring it up with your tutor and be totally honest about the whole situation, or you can ignore it and hope it'll go away. If you do the former, there may be some minor repercussions [but I can't imagine much if you only used a couple of sentences] but if you do the latter, it'll always be on your mind, and you also wouldn't want them to find out in retrospect and mark you down.

If you have letters which say you have mitigating circumstance, this is good, but you should have addressed this with your uni at the time you received them, especially since there was a chance that the situation would affect your work. Still, most tutors are human beings and are likely to be sympathetic to your situation *as long as you address it sooner rather than later*.

I would bite the bullet and address it with your tutor. Go all in and explain what you were going through and what led you to do what you did. It's not *that* bad but you don't want the situation to get worse, which it has the potential to  the longer it goes unaddressed. Good luck.